# Antl Grammar with brackets and whitespace

Tags: antlr, antlr4

i'm using AntlrWords 2.1 to create a grammar for antlr v4. The rParanthesis is not recognised for whatever reason. I have searched a lot but couldnt find a reason why. Can you find any errors?

```
grammar bracketsGrammar;

OPENINGBRACKET : '[';
CLOSINGBRACKET : ']';

lParanthesis : OPENINGBRACKET ;
rParanthesis : CLOSINGBRACKET ;

WS : ' ' ->skip;
WORD : ~[ "]+ ;

parenthesizedWord : lParanthesis WS+ WORD WS+ rParanthesis ;

fullfile: parenthesizedWord EOF ;
```

And my input is

```
[ Manuel ]
```

And the output is

```
(fullfile (parenthesizedWord (lParanthesis [) Manuel ]) <EOF>)
```

As you can see both [ and ] are part of the output but my rParanthesis is not recognised.

Thanks for your help
Manuel

Comment: Have you considered [GrammarLexer.g4](https://github.com/sharwell/antlrworks2/blob/master/org-antlr-works-editor/src/org/antlr/works/editor/grammar/experimental/GrammarLexer.g4) and [GrammarParser.g4](https://github.com/sharwell/antlrworks2/blob/master/org-antlr-works-editor/src/org/antlr/works/editor/grammar/experimental/GrammarParser.g4)?

Comment: I don't see anything here about "output". Exactly how are you producing your output?

Comment: The output is created using ANTLRWorks 2.1, there you can choose Run->Run in TestRig... which gives you the resulting tokenlist and the resulting tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `skip` spaces in the lexer but are using the `WS` token inside parser rules: remove them.

It shouldn't be:

```
parenthesizedWord : lParanthesis WS+ WORD WS+ rParanthesis ;
```

but:

```
parenthesizedWord : lParanthesis WORD rParanthesis ;
```

instead.

And then the following parse tree will be created:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that was it. I though that I still have to consider the whitespaces but it makes sense if they are skipped to exclude them from the parser rules Thanks

Comment: What if we need one space after and before brackets? Can you please tell me @Bart Kiers ?